# Returning a dynamic column with row count based on criteria | mySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I dynamically add a row count column to the following select statement based on results criteria - for example:

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table1.address,
    table1.job,
    table2.birthday
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
WHERE
    table2.job = "Doctor"
```

**Intended Results:**

[image: Intended Results Table]

The dynamic count is counting the returned rows based on the birthday - if the birthday is different the count resets to 1 and counts.

If it is not possible in mySQL, please note I will be executing this statement in PDO, is there a way to add a dynamic count afterwards? Perhaps using PHP.

Comment: This is a rank within a group. If you have window functions, you can use the `RANK()` function.

Comment: Can you please show how this can be done? I appreciate your help

Comment: In PHP, save the date in a variable, and increment a counter variable. If the current row's date is different from the variable, set the counter back to 1.

Comment: Understood, Is there anyway to do this using only mySQL?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can use the `RANK()` window function in MySQL 8.x. Before that you can use a user-defined variable.